# Stuck In su in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, su

I accidentally did

```
su
```

with no arguments while logged into the root account.

It then put me into su and at the beginning of the command line, it now shows

```
-bash-4.1#
```

How do I "get out of" su and return back to just root?

Answer (score 4):

Same way you get out of every other shell.

```
exit
```

Comment: OR pressing CTRL-d at the prompt

Comment: But when I do exit, it just completely quits out of PuTTY and when I log back in, its still showing the same.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; `su` shouldn't have caused that. Did you perhaps do something else?

Comment: It was just su and maybe a - at the end if I can try to remember my hardest.

Comment: If I completely restart the system will it fix it?

Comment: No, since that has nothing to do with it. And the comments in the other answer imply that something has been done to your system.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I just restarted the system, still is in su it seems. Is there any hard reset way to guarantee I get out of this?

Comment: It is not "stuck in su". **Your shell configuration files are missing.** Copy them back from `/etc/skel`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Where do I copy those to?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is there a user directory for root? If so where? I have no clue where to copy these files.

Comment: `/root` is normally the home directory of root.

Answer (score 0):

su and root are the same thing.

To login as another user, do

```
su username
```

Comment: But how do I return to the normal

    [root@hostname]#

Comment: that is just the prompt you are talking about. you can do exit to leave the current prompt or do "source ~/.bashrc" or "source ~/.cshrc" to source default profile of your shell.

Comment: That returns No such file or directory on CentOS 6